# didSet called when getting a property declared as a protocol

Tags: swift, protocols, swift2, option-type

Here's some code:

```
import UIKit

protocol ViewModelProtocol {
    var price: String { get }
}

class ViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    var price: String {
        return "$420"
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // If you change the type to ViewModel directly, no infinite loop
    var viewModel: ViewModelProtocol? = nil {
        didSet {
            print("viewModel didSet called")
            updateDisplay()
        }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        viewModel = ViewModel()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        updateDisplay()
    }

    func updateDisplay() {
        print("In updateDisplay()")
        print("\(viewModel?.price)")
        // if you access the viewModel like this, no infinite loop
        // if let v = viewModel {
        //     print("\(v.price)")
        // }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

This code will run in an infinite loop. Specifically, it bounces between `print("\(viewModel?.price)")` in `updateDisplay()` and the `didSet` for `viewModel`.

If you change `viewModel`'s type to `ViewModel` directly (skipping the protocol), the infinite loop disappears. Alternatively, if you unwrap `viewModel` in `updateDisplay()` before using it the infinite loop also disappears.

This is in Swift 2, although I haven't verified if it has the same behavior in earlier Swift. One other data point, calling methods on the protocol doesn't cause a call to `didSet`.

Does this look like a Swift bug to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that not only I have this problem with didSet{}.
There is open radar for this issue: https://openradar.appspot.com/22574299

Answer (score 2):

It's a very impressive case.

It maybe a problem with your willSet attribute with your protocol type having a readonly attribute inside. I made a lots of tests and it's being very hard to find a solutions. But, if you really need to keep going in this way... I think the follow change can help you

```
protocol ViewModelProtocol {
    var price: String { get set }
}

class ViewModel: ViewModelProtocol {
    var price: String  {
        get {
            return "$420"
        }

        set {
            return 
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

As you said... The problem only happens when try to access directly the price attribute via viewModel object

I just put my answer here, cause it didn't fit in comment field size.

But is very impressive... I will try to find a final solution. :)